# Android-Priority-Jobqueue Surviving Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-priority-jobqueue

I'm trying to implement the library below to survive orientation changes:
https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue

Here's my configuration:

```
 Configuration config = new Configuration.Builder(getApplication())
                .consumerKeepAlive(45)
                .maxConsumerCount(3)
                .minConsumerCount(1)
                .build();
        return new JobManager(config);
```

Here's my example job:

```
public class CounterJob extends Job {
    private int countTo;

    protected CounterJob(int countTo, Params params) {
        super(params);
        this.countTo = countTo;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdded() {
        Log.e("counting to", "" + countTo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRun() throws Throwable {
        Log.e("running job", "" + countTo);
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < countTo; i++) {
            total += i;
        }

        Log.e("total", "" + total);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancel(int cancelReason, @Nullable Throwable throwable) {

    }

    @Override
    protected RetryConstraint shouldReRunOnThrowable(@NonNull Throwable throwable, int runCount, int maxRunCount) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's an example Controller for counting:

```
public class CounterController {
    private JobManager mJobManager;

    public CounterController(JobManager jobManager) {
        this.mJobManager = jobManager;
    }

    public void count(int countTo) {
        mJobManager.addJobInBackground(new CounterJob(countTo, new Params(1).requireNetwork().persist()));
    }
}
```

And i call like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCounterController.count(1000000000);
}
```

When i rotate the device same job starts again. So if i'm not wrong, if i'm doing a network call, when orientation changed it'll duplicate the request.

I think there's a problem about my implementation. I tried to implement as example in library page. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are re-creating the job when you rotate so then you end up with 2 jobs. You should not enqueue it twice when activity changes configuration (a.k.a. rotation).

Comment: i can check it manually but my point is, i'm wondering to know if library has an ability that ignoring same job created in a time period or join it with the first created.

Comment: The library does not know about orientation change but it has a way to avoid duplicate jobs.
http://yigit.github.io/android-priority-jobqueue/javadoc/com/birbit/android/jobqueue/Params.html#singleInstanceBy-java.lang.String-

Note that this will only work if the previous one is in the queue.

Comment: so if original job is running still job'll be duplicated.

Comment: Note: this library is deprecated now, use WorkManager instead (for persistent jobs). For non-persistent jobs, use Corouties as recommended here https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : you can give a group ID then a ID to the job so it won t be running again. Here is the javadoc :

/////// for the group ///////

> /**
>        * Sets the group id. Jobs in the same group are guaranteed to execute sequentially.
>        * @param groupId which group this job belongs (can be null of course)
>        * @return this
>        */

```
public Params groupBy(String groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
    return this;
}
```

////////for the ID ////////

> /**
>        * Sets the single instance id. If there is another Job with the same single id queued and
>        * not yet running, this Job will get {@link Job#onCancel(int, Throwable)} called immediately after
>        * {@link Job#onAdded()} and only the previous Job will run. That is, {@link Job#onRun()}
>        * will only be called once.
>        *
>
> If no group id was set, one will be set automatically.
>        * @param singleId which single instance group this job belongs to (can be null of course)
>        * @return this
>        */

```
public Params singleInstanceBy(String singleId) {
    this.singleId = singleId;
    return this;
}
```

You set it in the constructor methods

```
  public Step1Jobs() {
        super(new Params(Priority.LOW).requireNetwork().groupBy(STEPS).singleInstanceBy(STEP1));
    }
```

Comment: if i'm not wrong if the job is currently executed, checking with id will not work  in my case as doc says: If there is another Job with the same single id queued and * not yet running.

Comment: You can try and let me know ^^ Another solution will be to use a lib like Icepick and keep the state of a boolean and if this boolean is true then you lanch your  job et then put it on false (sorry for my english)

Comment: i think there's no need to try because of yigit's answer. we need to create a mechanism for handling rotation.